# Coloring (W-L Method)

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, first-order-logic, coloring

I am trying to read [An Optimal Lower Bound on the Number of
Variables for Graph Identification](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwieiOKq6ZDNAhVMto8KHbs3BEoQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.umass.edu%2F~immerman%2Fpub%2Fopt.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFRF9Vm8Het8kHm163djV7mGU-TUg&sig2=UhhjJwSZNFjnwoyO81rIHw). On page 3 (4th paragraph), it is written-

> It might color vertices and edges implicitly by using $k$-tuples with
>   repetition of components. It could start with some encoding of the
>   graph into the labels assigned to the $k$-tuples. For example, the
>   initial label or color of every $k$-tuple could be the number of its
>   distinct components except when this number is two. Then two colors
>   could be used  to encode the presence or absence of an edge between
>   the two vertices. We prefer to get a quicker start by initially
>   coloring each $k$-tuple with its isomorphism type. Repeatedly, the color
>   of $(u_1, . . . , u_k)$ is refined by the $n$ element multiset
>   (containing one element for each vertex $v$) of $k$-tuples of colors
>   previously assigned to
>
> $(v, u_2, . . . , u_k), (u_1, v, u_3, . . . , u_k), . . . , (u_1, . .
>  . , u_{k−1}, v)$
>
> We only need to consider $k$-tuples of distinct elements, if we finally color the vertices by the multiset of colors of incident $k$-tuples.

I am having hard time get this passage. I would appreciate some help about the coloring  with some example. Note that, if $k=1$ , then it is simple vertex classification (partition based on degree).

Comment: What is the isomorphism type of a $ k$-tuple of vertices? I would think it is it the isomorphism type of the induced subgraph, but this is not consistent with $ k = 1 $ being classification by degree.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$k$ Dimensional Weisfeiler-Lehman Method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411090/k-dimensional-weisfeiler-lehman-method)